# Is it safe to remove the namespace definition from a new class in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces

When you create a new class in visual studio it includes a namespace definition which is pulled from the default namespace set in the project properties. However if you remove the namespace definition it picks up the default namespace anyway. Is it safe to remove and is there any benefit to leaving it there?

Comment: Either, I've found the same in both i.e. I can remove the namespace from the class file, search for the class in the object browser and see that the class does in fact reside in the default namespace

Comment: Actually on closer look c# and vb .net do behave differently. Because my assembly was named the same as the default namespace the class looked like it did belong to the namespace however was infact in the global namespace in c#. In vb.net the same code does appear to add the class to the default namespace and not the global namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c# the class does not automatically use the default namespace but instead will reside in the global namespace which is generally not recommended.

In VB.NET the class will automatically use the default namespace and not the global namespace and is safe however this is not the best practise. As Pavel Minaev mentions below...

> In VB context, it is safe, but a good rule of thumb is that "explicit is better than implicit". Personally, I've always found VB implicit namespace and imports to be a good example of misfeatures that hamper code readability more than they help conciseness. But, of course, it is very subjective.

Comment: Thought I'd make clear the differences between c# and vb.net for completeness sake

Answer (score 3):

In VB context, it is safe, but a good rule of thumb is that "explicit is better than implicit". Personally, I've always found VB implicit namespace and imports to be a good example of misfeatures that hamper code readability more than they help conciseness. But, of course, it is very subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it's possible and legal, but... it's just not nice :) (in 99% cases). When you are writing your code, it's nice to "pack" it inside some namespace.
Also, you won't have problems with name conflicts (fe. 2 classes with identical name - legal and manageable if you will have them in separate namespaces.
Basically:
 1. Having stuff in global namespace isn't nice (it's not the same as "default" namespace)
 2. Namespaces allow you to easier manage your code (and this is a benefit of leaving even the default namespace instead of removing it)
 3. Namespaces help to resolve name conflicts etc.

Answer (score 0):

It does not pick up the default namespace, in general. In general, it puts it into the global namespace, which is not the same thing.

If you want the class to be in a namespace, then leave the `namespace` in place.

Comment: I strongly suspect the question was asked in VB context.